# ECDSA dA multiplication algorithm

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I was looking at this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42104/can-you-help-me-understand-this-toy-example-of-ecdsa-signing-and-verification) and i can`t understand this part:

> QA = dA G
>
> = 5 (5,1)
>
> = (9,16)

I saw that algorithm used for this was Double-and-add algorithm but i didn't get it. Can anyone explain how can i do this calculation on papir?

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Problem on Elliptic Curve Point Doubling](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64457/18298)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a right direction

Comment: @FilipFilipovic Does the linked question answer your question in a satisfactory manner?

Comment: @EllaRose Yes, that explains it very good.

Comment: I've closed the question (putting it on hold) as you've indicated that the other Q/A already explains your problem. If you have any remaining / followup question it is probably best to create a new one. And welcome to crypto, of course :)